Flutter CustomPainter BlendMode feature
In the below code on srcPaint, I set blendMode = BlendMode.srcIn. Then, the srcPath should draw only the part that overlaps the dstPath, and the remaining parts of dstPath and srcPath should be hidden. But here are both paths drawn. How can I fix this?
    class ShapeBlender extends CustomPainter {
        @override
        void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
            var dstPath = Path()..addRect(Rect.fromLTWH(50, 50, 100, 100));
            var srcPath = Path()..addOval(Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, 100, 100));
        
            var dstPaint = Paint()..color = Colors.red;
            var srcPaint = Paint()
              ..color = Colors.blue
              ..blendMode = BlendMode.srcIn;
        
            canvas.drawPath(dstPath, dstPaint);
            canvas.drawPath(srcPath, srcPaint);
        }
      
        @override
        bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) => false;
    }

Output:


anyway, if you really want BlendMode first call this: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Canvas/saveLayer.html but remember it's a rather expensive operation

I actually need to blend two items (image/text, shape, or imagine those are widget). Where item2 only shows up in that part where item1 overlaps,. So here, the BlendMode feature is important to me.

so if you really need it then as I said use saveLayer

Can you suggest to me, how to Blend two widgets?

see https://github.com/gskinnerTeam/flutter_vignettes/blob/master/vignettes/_shared/lib/ui/blend_mask.dart (or/and other source files in the same folder)
