Flutter BlendMode between two widget
I want to blend two widgets with the BlendMode feature. But I'm unable to find such a widget. How can I fix this?
My problem is that, I want to animate two widgets (text, image, or shape). Whenever they overlap, the overlap part will apply the blend effect.
For example, the image below shows the BlendMode.xor effect between a balloon and a pigeon.


"But I'm unable to find such a widget. How can I fix this?" - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78394917/flutter-custompainter-blendmode-feature#comment138207990_78394917

@pskink! I've tried it. it doesn't meet my requirements. even when I use the BlendMask widget with Blend.xor,srcIn, etc it becomes a full black color instead of a transparent partial color.

run this demo: https://github.com/gskinnerTeam/flutter_vignettes/tree/master/vignettes/indie_3d - it uses BlendMask widget - the output is something like this

No. The BlendMode.srcIn, BlendMode.dstIn, BlendMode.xor etc not work
